# Isotope.js: reveal hidden items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope v2 & having some trouble revealing previously hidden items. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

To start, I'm gathering an array of jQuery objects & telling Isotope to hide them. This works perfectly:

```
elements.postsToHide.push($(elements.gridBlock + "#" + v.SocialPostId)); // $(".block#block123")
elements.grid.isotope("hide", elements.postsToHide).isotope();
```

Eventually, I'd like to reveal these hidden items again. So, on click of a button, I'm doing the following, which does not reveal anything:

```
elements.grid.isotope("reveal", elements.postsToHide);
```

[The docs say](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#hide) "hide" & "reveal" take and Array of Isotope.Items, which I *believe* I'm passing properly.

When I call the reveal method, my console says "Uncaught Error: undefined is not a function".

I'm perplexed as to why I can push into an array and hide items, but the same array cannot be revealed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue request, Isotope/Masonry `hide` and `reveal` methods are mostly internal and aren't the easiest to use.

To get around the issues I was having was to:

1. push items to hide into an array
2. each through the items and use jQuery `.hide()`
3. once each is done, call .isotope() again to layout grid with newly hidden items
4. to reveal, each through the items and use jQuery `.show`, then call .isotope again

Answer (score 0):

i did something like this

```
        //swipe.
    $('.grid').on('swiperight', '.grid-item', function(event) {
        $(this).hide().fadeOut('500', function() {
            $('.grid').isotope('hide', this).isotope('layout');
        });
    });

    $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.grid-item').show().fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('.grid').isotope('reveal', this).isotope('layout');
        });
    });
```

i used hide/show before calling the method